# Lost previous entity data after submit form Symfony 3

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

Here is a part of my controller edit action. Method is `PUT`.

```
 public function editRentalAction(Request $request, Rental $rental): JsonResponse
 {
    $rentalManager = $this->get('rental.rental_manager');

    $form = $this->createForm(RentalType::class, $rental);
    $form->submit(json_decode($request->getContent(), true));
```

When I try to submit some entity data(thats which i want to update) from request, all other entity data are lost( set as `null`). How could i change only this params which i sent ?

request payload:

```
{"example_parameter": "example"}
```

Comment: which symfony version are you using exactly?

Comment: It is Symfony 3.3

Answer (score 3):

The solution is set second argument in `submit()` to `false` and change method to `PATCH`

Here is description: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/direct_submit.html#form-call-submit-directly

Answer (score 2):

`PUT` will nullify empty properties.

**Best solution:** Use `PATCH` instead of `PUT`.

**Alternative:** Sent the entire object with `PUT` (not only updated properties).

Comment: `PATH` has the same problem